# Filtering a datatable row using a where clause

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset, where-clause, datarow

I have a DataTable that I am pulling from a DataSet. From the DataTable, I want to use the Where clause to return a particular row. I looked at "[How can I select a row from a datatable using two variable values?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6363565/72324)" but I get an error

> "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.DataRow[]' to
>   'System.Data.DataRow'"

I searched google, but could not find a solution.

My code is:

```
mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet);

DataTable dtTable = myDataSet.Tables[0];
DataRow dr = dtTable.Select("VendorID = " + Session["VendorId"].ToString());
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50.aspx) method of a DataTable returns an array of DataRow even if your query selects only one row

```
DataRow[] dr = dtTable.Select("VendorID = " + Session["VendorId"].ToString());
```

Then, if you really expects just one row, you could easily grab the expected row checking for the length of the array. In this case it is my opinion that no fancy Enumerable extension methods are really needed

```
if(dr.Length > 0)
{
    string avalue = dr[0]["AColumnName"].ToString();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Select() is returning an array of rows, and you're assigning it to a single row.

You can do :

```
DataRow dr = dtTable.Select("VendorID = " + Session["VendorId"].ToString()).First();
```

or

```
var dr = dtTable.Select("VendorID = " + Session["VendorId"].ToString());
```

which will give you an array of rows.

Comment: Can't find FirstOrDefault in intellisense

Comment: You need .net >= 3.5 and a reference to System.Data.DataSetExtensions and System.Linq for this to work..

Answer (score 0):

Asuming there is only one unique result

```
DataTable dtTable = myDataSet.Tables[0];
DataRow[] drs = dtTable.Select("VendorID = " + Session["VendorId"].ToString());
if(drs.Length > 0)
    DataRow dr = drs[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

`DataTable.Select()` returns an array of `DataRow`.

```
DataRow[] dr = dtTable.Select("VendorID = " + Session["VendorId"].ToString());
```

If you only want the first record,

```
DataRow[] dr = dtTable.Select("VendorID = " + Session["VendorId"].ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the method `First()`:

```
DataRow dr = dtTable.Select("VendorID = " + Session["VendorId"].ToString()).First();
```

Answer (score 0):

The Select() method returns an IEnumerable collection with one DataRow inside, in your case. You must extract the DataRow from that collection with FirstOrDefault() instead.