# From Datatable to Datatable to List

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

Hello sir i am not native english, new here in stackoverflow and new in programming but i will try my best to share my problem with you:
I added some comments in my code so i hope you can better see what the problems are 
i am trying to make something like a temporary datatable that gets informations (only the rows matter) from 1 specific datatable(there will be more see in the code) and the "temporarydatatable" gives these to a list<> i tried it with linq. ofc i have my own mind and tried to change it a way i understand ([LINQ query on a DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855/linq-query-on-a-datatable) this wasnt really helpful for me :X ) and i tried some other things as well but i dont want to smash 10 links here :P 
so here comes the code:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    datatable1();

}

public void datatable1()
{
    /*This Table should get the informations from datatable_1 or
    another one (there will be some more tables and the viewtable will 
    get the informations from the table where the 
    Type ==(i guess it will be a combobox) selected Type */
    DataTable viewtable = new DataTable();
    viewtable.Columns.Add("Typ", typeof(string));
    viewtable.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
    viewtable.Columns.Add("Anzahl", typeof(string));
    viewtable.Columns.Add("Zeit", typeof(string));
    /*here is the main problem i have*/     
    viewtable.Rows =from _Row1 in datatable_1 where "Typ" =="Una";
    /*it "worked" like this so i get the informations in my list*/    
    viewtable.Rows.Add("Una", "Testschrank2", "9000", "0:20:30");

    //this table is a example table holding the informations 
     DataTable datatable_1 = new DataTable();
     datatable_1.Clear();
     datatable_1.Columns.Add("Typ");
     datatable_1.Columns.Add("Name");
     datatable_1.Columns.Add("Anzahl");
     datatable_1.Columns.Add("Zeit");
     DataRow _Row1 = datatable_1.NewRow();
     datatable_1.Rows.Add("Una", "Testschrank2", "9000", "0:20:30");
    // _Row1["Zeit"] = (4, 30, 0);
    datatable_1.Rows.Add(_Row1);`
}
```

well i guess i added too much code but like i said i am really new to this so its a bit difficult for me to point on my problem with little code excuse me sir
and
thanks for your help o/

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: the key part: `var fromRow = fromTable.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().First(x=>someconvert x[columnIndex]==yourvalue); toTable.ImportRow(fromRow);`

Comment: is this the order in which your code is in your program? it looks like it won't compile this way

Comment: i hoped it would be clear like this i am trying to get the rows from datatable_1 in the datatable viewtable but this way it doesn work

Comment: well everything is fine except the line : viewtable.Rows =from _Row1 in datatable_1 where "Typ" =="Una"   ;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the value from the first `DataTable` you have to pull all `DataRows` from it as [Lei Yang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1518100/lei-yang) suggested in his comment.

```
DataRow temp = datatable_1.Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
                          .SingleOrDefault(x=>x["Typ"].ToString() == "Una");
```

1: You cannot assign to the property `Rows` since it is `readonly`.

2: You cannot just use simply `viewtable.Rows.Add(temp)` because this row already belongs to another table. This will result in a [System.ArgumentException](https://stackoverflow.com/a/722060/5174469)

So you need to import the row:

```
if (temp != null)
{
    viewtable.ImportRow(temp);
}
```

EDIT:

If you intend to capture more than one row using the `where` clause you can use a `List<DataRow>` to save them temporarily and import each row afterwards in a loop:

```
List<DataRow> temp = datatable_1.Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
                                .Where(x => x["Typ"].ToString() == "Una").ToList();


if (temp.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (var row in temp)
    {
        viewtable.ImportRow(row);
    }
}
```

EDIT 2:

Here are some sources for further research:

[How to: Locate a Specific Row in a DataTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y06xa2h1.aspx)

In this example you can use also the [Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/b5c0xc84(v=vs.110).aspx) method to get the desired rows. This would look like this:

```
DataRow [] temp2 = datatable_1.Select("Typ ='Una'", "Name DESC", DataViewRowState.Added);

// or the short version:
DataRow [] temp2 = datatable_1.Select("Typ ='Una'");
```

the outcome will be the same. This version is from a an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17534771/5174469) to a similar question.

Comment: If you expect multiple matches, use `Where` instead of `SingleOrDefault` use `ImportRow` in a loop over the matches.

Comment: thanks @ Mong Zhu & Lei Yang it works for now so finally i can continue :P

Comment: @wkl valid point, thank you, I made an edit to accommodate for this

Comment: oh one more thing @MongZhu have you created this on your own or is there a source you can link?

Comment: @Pr0gr4mm3r I had the same Idea as Lei Yang, for the import example I did a little research, so I posted the link. There is definitely some source on the internet for this answer, many probably. You just need to search for it

Comment: @Pr0gr4mm3r I edited my answer and included a second option to filter the `DataTable` with some links for further research.

Comment: thanks a lot :) well the problem is that i am really really new and often i dont get it what they try to explain or cant Convert.To myCode :P anyway thanks a lot again you helped me a lot ;)

Comment: @Pr0gr4mm3r It is difficult in the beginning to find the right keywords for the research. But as you advance in programming you will be able to better articulate what problem you have at hand and especially what you want to do. In this case I would start researching with "c# datatable get specific row " and if your code throws exceptions check the details and search for exactly this text from the exception. Good fortune.